# Intercept an event or track an event of custom control in iOs

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton, custom-controls

I am creating a custom `UIButton`.
So when an app uses this button and obviously has a method bound to the `UIControleventtouchdown` event of it. I want to do a certain operation before the click method is called.

So is it possible to intercept the call and do some operation before passing on to the method bound to the `UIControleventtouchdown` event?

Comment: Why do you want this, what do you want to do earlier?

Comment: I would want to track the number of times the button was initiated/rendered and clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If your `CustomButton` simply override [sendAction(_:to:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol/1618237-sendaction)

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    override func sendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, for event: UIEvent?) {
        // perform custom operations here
        super.sendAction(action, to: target, for: event)
    }
}
```